# How to convert string to date in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

How do I convert a string to date time in Python ? I have the string 09082010 .how do I convert to 09-08-2010?.Thank you.

Comment: `datetime.strptime('09082010', '%m%d%Y').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')`

Comment: @zondo add that as an answer so I can upvote that too

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

mydate = datetime.strptime('09082010', '%d%m%Y')
```

Comment: @L.Scottohnson, try to provide a brief explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your date strings will be in the format mmddyyyy like the example you provided then this should work for you.

```
import datetime

d="09012010"
mm=d[:2]
dd=d[2:4]
yr=d[4:]

date = datetime.date(day=dd, month=mm, year=yr)
```